# Keyword not supported: '"data source', Calling Strings From Appsettings in App.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I receive the above error when reading a database string from `app.config`. 
The code is below:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
   public string conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ssqlstring"];
}
```

The connection is created here:

```
string sqlstr = "\"" + conStr + "\"";
string connectionString = sqlstr;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

In app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="Data Source=xxxx\\xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

The full error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

Is there a way to get the stings to work with `AppSetings`? I was having too many problems with `ConnectionString`.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `connectionStrings` in your `App.Config` file like this:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ssqlstring"
    connectionString="Data Source=xxxx\\xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And in the code behind:

```
string conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ssqlstring"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
```

Comment: I am getting the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object...even though I have a reference to System.Configuration

Comment: For some reason, I get the same error. I added System.Configuration. manually as well as stated 'using System.Configuration.'

Comment: Yes, however there is a warning, Warnin---The 'configuration' element is not declared. I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: The 'configuration' element is not declared is simply a warning; so your application should still compile. if you have problem with `ConfigurationManager` just add `System.Configuration` to your references. I have tested my answer in my VS. it works fine. Try it and let me know if it works for you finally. :)